# What does the word "attic" mean when referred to as a status?

Tags: meaning

In a report of a software issue (or bug) [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2095/), the status of the issue is described as:

> Status: attic
>
> ...
>
> Status: open --> attic

What does the word "attic" mean here?

I know attic usually [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attic)

> a room or a space immediately below the roof of a building

But I am not sure what it means here when referring to a reported issue.

Comment: Surely your own guessed understanding of this figurative use of this word *attic* will be just as good as anybody else will be able to come up with, don’t you think? And what **is** your guess, by the way?

Comment: It looks like a typo - it should be "**active**" but autocorrect changed it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a common technical term, but I would guess that the *attic* is where they put bugs they don't expect to fix soon. This is based on the traditional use of an attic (at least in parts of the US) to store random junk that people don't need anymore but for some reason or another don't want to throw away.

Other systems might call this the *backlog* or *no plans*. In the tracking system I work with every day, we've given this status the no less confusing name *> 18 months*, to indicate that we don't expect to resolve it in the next year and a half at least.

So unfortunately, I would not expect your bug report to see action any time soon.

Comment: True, it's not common. Also, CVS, the version control system, explicitly had an attic directory for certain files no longer in use. It seems like someone has configured JIRA with that same idea in mind. See https://www.gnu.org/software/trans-coord/manual/cvs/html_node/Attic.html.

Comment: Please do not use code-formatting backticks  for English "mentions". Set them in *italic* or use proper quotation marks. We do not have computer code here.

Comment: I think it's a bit more severe than putting it in the backlog or 18-month pile; it's saying it will be stored away (out of sight and forgotten about) for an arbitrarily long period and quite possibly never fixed. To me a backlog is a list of things you intend to fix given time, an attic is a place to store junk that you can't quite bring yourself to throw out.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Attic) has a (probably) relevant article:

> **Apache Attic**
>
> Apache Attic is a project of Apache Software Foundation to provide
> processes to make it clear when an Apache project has reached its
> end-of-life. The Attic project was created in November 2008. Also the
> retired projects can be retained.
>
> Projects may not stay in the attic forever: e.g. Apache XMLBeans is
> now a project of Apache Poi, but was previously in the attic from July
> 2013 until June 2018.

So one would guess a parallel usage: not totally deleted, but not being actively pursued / addressed.